# New windows open below (horizontal split) by default

Tags: init-file, buffers, window, window-splitting

Before, I used to have that windows would open on the right of my current window for things like `M-x man` and `M-x shell`. Now I have that they open below. All I've done is uninstall and reinstall my emacs via homebrew (was trying to get rid of `invalid image type: svg` unsuccessfully). Here is my `init.el`:

```
;; the next two lines make tabs into 4 spaces

(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
(setq-default tab-width 4)

;; the next lines are intended to make 'man-mode' easier to use

(global-set-key (kbd "M-o") 'man)

(defun shell-other-window ()
  "Open a `shell' in a new window."
  (interactive)
  (let ((buf (shell)))
    (switch-to-buffer (other-buffer buf))
    (switch-to-buffer-other-window buf)))

(global-set-key (kbd "M-p") 'shell-other-window)
```

Specifically, when I type `M-o RET read(2)`, I would like it to open in a new window to the right, not below. I have my `Man-notify-method` set as `friendly`.

Comment: Lookup (if you didn't yet) `display-buffer-alist` and `display-buffer` docs in Emacs and related topics here for a starter.  Also  'M-: (info "(emacs) Window Choice")'.

Comment: have you tried with `emacs -q` and `emacs -Q`?

Comment: Also to deal with the `invalid image type: svg` issue, add `(add-to-list 'image-types 'svg)` to your init file.